# Convert gridview string to varchar for sql insert statement in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I want to use a `datagrid` item as a variable in an `insert` statement. I can't figure out how to convert the string value to `varchar`.

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
 { 
     string ord = grdDisplayOrd.Rows[1].Cells[2].Text;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@ord", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ord; 
 }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What error you getting show us complete code.

Comment: Error information would be helpful for us to help you.

Comment: Show us the aspx markup of the GridView. It would also be  helpful to know the context of above code. Is it correct that you always want the value from the second row?

Comment: You might need to cast grdDisplayOrd as a TextBox....think i've had that problem before.

Comment: I am doing this from the top of my head: cmd.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() {Name="@ord", DbType=SqlDbType.VarChar, Value=ord))

Comment: When specifying `SqlDbType.VarChar`, you should **always** explicitly specify a **length** - otherwise you might end up having a string of 1 character length in the end.....

Comment: I just added the  "AddWithValue" and that fixed it. There was a solution to do this posted by someone on here and now he deleted that post.

Comment: @Tamir: The previous comment was addressed to you(voted to undelete).

Comment: @Tim - Thank you, he should get the credit for the answer. I will also work on being more specific about my error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't supply any error message, but maybe it because you didn't specified the SqlParameter length.
Anyway, try using

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ord", ord);`

it will auto recognized your type.